# Unable to get go package installed

Tags: go

Go Environment:

```
$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/stack/mygo"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/home/stack/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/home/stack/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT="1"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Go version:

```
$ go version
go version go1.6 linux/amd64
```

Error while running:

```
$ sudo -E  go get -u golang.org/x/crypto/ssh
package golang.org/x/crypto/ssh
    imports bufio: unrecognized import path "bufio"
package golang.org/x/crypto/ssh
    imports bytes: unrecognized import path "bytes"
package golang.org/x/crypto/ssh
    imports crypto: unrecognized import path "crypto"
package golang.org/x/crypto/ssh
```

Comment: You showed your `go env` with some user, then you do `go get` with another user (`sudo -E go get`) which might have different `go env`.

Comment: Thanks @icza for quick response.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo -E` changes you to root and preserves the environment variables. In this case, these are the env variables of the shell and not of `go`.

You can read more about how sudo -E works [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178303/how-does-sudo-e-work-here)

Since your `GOTOOLDIR="/home/stack/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"` shows that it is installed for the user `stack` (probably) - you have to use `go get` as user `stack`

Comment: Thanks @Hugo.  I was able to solve this without having to use sudo, so that it run go get as stack user.  Earlier I was having permission issue thats the reason I used sudo -E to preserve environment variables, but that changes the user to root with env preserved as you guys mentioned.  I changed the ownership of folder pointed by GOPATH to stack and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

[Godep and vendor](https://github.com/tools/godep) is worth looking into. Just like package managers like npm and pip, working with dependencies within the project directory prevent you from version clashes and avoid using `$GOPATH`.

A simpler alternative is [Glide](https://glide.sh/). It greatly simplifies dependency management and works very similar to `Godep` with `glide.yaml` and `glide.lock` files to control dependencies and their versions instead of `Godep.json`.

If you've worked with `npm` or `cargo`, it's very similar:

```
# Create manifest
$ glide init

# Get packages
$ glide get path/to/package

# Update package
$ glide update

# Remove package
$ glide remove path/to/package
```

Packages are saved to `vendor/` just like Godep does (in default Go 1.6 any way).